# Entity Framework Insert into a many-to-many instance with already existing registers, creating duplicated registers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Well, I have this configuration:

- **Item** has 0 or many **Groups** and 0 or many **Users** (tables *GroupsItem* and *UsersItem*)
- **Groups** and **Users** are inside 0 or many **Items**
- **Groups** and **Users** are independently being created in the application

Here's the problem: When I try to insert a new **Item** I have to point out what are its **Groups** and **Users** (which already exists). When it happens, the tables *GroupsItem*, *UsersItem* and *Item* are being correctly populated, but I'm having duplicated registers at **Groups** and **Users**.

Here is my code summarized:

**Item**:

```
public class Item {
    public ICollection<Groups> GROUPS{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Users> USERS{ get; set; }
}
```

**Groups**: (**Users** have the same structure)

```
public class Groups{
    public ICollection<Item> ITEM { get; set; }
}
```

Inserting a new **Item**:

```
public static void InsertingItem(){
    Item example = new Item(){
        GROUPS = AlreadyExistingGroup()
    }
    using (myDbContext db = new myDbContext()){
        db.ITEMS.Add(example);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And that's it. `AlreadyExistingGroup` is a method that returns a `List<Groups>` which is populated with groups that already exist in the database, the method that brings these groups is a single function that brings one single group but it's called multiple times:

```
public static Groups FetchGroups(int id) {
        try {
            using (myDbContext db = new myDbContext ()) {
                Groups group = db.GROUPS.Where(x => x.CODGROUP == id).FirstOrDefault();
                return group;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
      }
```

What am I doing wrong that is causing duplicate registers at Groups and Users?

Comment: What does “duplicate registers” mean, that it is inserting duplicate copies of the users and groups?  If so, it means you’re attaching unattached users and groups via an entity that is tracked as Added so they will also be treated as added.  Attach the users/groups as Unmodified prior to saving changes

Comment: For example: I have a group "whatever" which have PK "1". When I insert a new Item that has "whatever" as its group, a new "whatever" is registered at the Groups table (with a different PK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Editing my answer with the correct solution we came to in comments:**

The issue lies with the two different DbContexts in the code:

```cs
public static void InsertingItem(){
    Item example = new Item(){
        // DbContext #1 is created in this method
        GROUPS = AlreadyExistingGroup(); 
    }
    // And this is DbContext #2
    using (myDbContext db = new myDbContext()){
        db.ITEMS.Add(example);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The fix is to use the same `DbContext` for both the lookup and the insert of a new item. Example:

```cs
public static void InsertingItem(){
    using (myDbContext db = new myDbContext()){
        Item example = new Item(){
            // refactor the AlreadyExistingGroup method to accept a DbContext, or to move
            // the code from the method here
            GROUPS = AlreadyExistingGroup(dbContext) ;
        }
        db.ITEMS.Add(example);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

<s>If I'm understanding your setup correctly, I think you'd want Groups to only have one parent Item reference.</s>

`public class Groups{
    public Item ITEM { get; set; } // 
}`

Also, and I'm not downvoting or criticizing, but just a suggestion: It's helpful to also post the model configuration as well when asking EF questions. Because... well... EF can be finicky. Aka:

`modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
  .HasMaxLength(50)
  .WhateverElseYouConfigure();`

Comment: But if I do as you said I would be doing a 1-to-many relationship. Right?

Comment: Correct. However, it looks like you want a many to many relationship, which can be configured via the model configuration. And if it’s a many to many relationship, we need to know which version of EF you’re using. EF or EF Core. EF can generate the junction table for you, but in EF Core, you have to explicitly create the model of the junction table in C#. Please show us the model configuration.

Comment: So, I'm probably using EF only. Because the junction table was created automatically. I know nothing about model configuration. Im using DataAnnotations and DataAnnotations.Schema only. Could you clarify?

Comment: @MWsan Please see Moho's answer. I just noticed how you're trying to insert the new item. Try doing the lookup of `AlreadyExistingGroup()` in the same dbcontext as `db.SaveChanges();` The problem lies in the two separate DBContexts you're using.

Comment: It worked! I tought that it was correct because it wasn't two separate DBContexts, but the same context being called two different times (two different connections). When I put everything inside the same `Using` it works. Create another answer that I'll mark as the correct one. Thank you.

Comment: @MWsan Glad it worked. I edited my original answer with the correct solution, so when you get a chance, if you would mark it as the accepted answer, I'd be super appreciative. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification in the comments it seems you are using untracked (unattached) `Group` and `User` entities when setting them in your new `Item` entity.  When the `Item` entity is added to the `Items` `DbSet`, it is tracked as `EntityState.Added`.  EF will propagate the `Item` entity's object graph and as it comes across untracked related entities (i.e. the `User` and `Group` collections you've set), it will track the formerly untracked entities as `EntityState.Added` as well, thus inserting new records in the data store for those entities.

To solve the problem, manually attach these related entities as `EntityState.Unchanged`.  As an example, you can use the [DbContext.AttachRange method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attachrange?view=efcore-2.1)

```
db.AttachRange( existingGroups );
```

Or per entity you can also attach via the [DbContext.Entry method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696578(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
db.Entry( existingGroup ); // this tracks the entity as Unchanged
```

Comment: It didn't worked because Im not using EF Core. AttachRange doesn't even exist in this context. I solved it using Jason 's answer: I did every EF operation inside the same Using , with the same opened connection. However, thank you so much for the help. I'll see more about EF Core, it seems to be more "configurable" then standard EF.